# Symbolic convex analysis toolkit for Maple

Tags: symbolic-computation, maple

I'm looking for the SCAT (Symbolic convex analysis toolkit) for Maple written by Hamilton and Borwein.

I have seen some references in the specialized literature than mention some urls. However, the links are dead.

#### References

1. Borwein, J.M. & Hamilton, C.H.: [Symbolic Fenchel Conjugation](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-007-0134-4).  Math. Program. (2009) 116: 17. doi:10.1007/s10107-007-0134-4
2. Hamilton, C.H.: [Symbolic convex analysis](http://docserver.carma.newcastle.edu.au/296/). Masters thesis, Simon Fraser University, (2005)

Answer (score 2):

A working link is provided in this site: http://vaopt.math.uni-goettingen.de/software.php